# Flutter always run on Chrome, how to switch to run on android emulator?

Tags: android, flutter

I tried to make my project run on Web

so I typed this command

```
flutter run -d chrome
```

But it always runs on chrome when i typed

```
flutter run
```

, I would like to switch to run on android emulator
How to switch to run android emulator?? Thank you very much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using Visual Studio Code, you can select the device your app should run on the bottom-right and then, run the app by pressing CTRL + F5(F5 to run it with debugging) or from the top-right.

[image: button to select device]

Your preferred device is Chrome(web-javascript), right now.
You may need to go in main.dart to run the app, it is a VSCode bug.

Otherwise, you can run the command: `flutter emulators --launch <device_name>` and `flutter run`.

Answer (score 4):

check device Id by running

```
adb devices
```

then run with deviceId

```
flutter run -d yourDeviceId
```

Let me know any issues you find in comments